# Hive Error : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have got twitter data using flume on HDFS. Have 3 node cluster and MySQL Metastore for hive.

When i execute below query

```
select user_name.screen_name, user_name.followers_count from BBMP_election_tweets limit 10;
```

It is giving proper results.

But if i run below query

```
select user_name.screen_name, user_name.followers_count c from BBMP_election_tweets order by c desc;
```

It throws below error

> Query ID = hduser_20150827102628_15a405ae-59a4-4c90-aa47-045d58c62f02
>   Total jobs = 1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks
>   determined at compile time: 1 In order to change the average load for
>   a reducer (in bytes):   set
>   hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer= In order to limit the
>   maximum number of reducers:   set hive.exec.reducers.max= In
>   order to set a constant number of reducers:   set
>   mapreduce.job.reduces= Starting Job = job_1439458788229_0016,
>   Tracking URL =
>   http://hdmaster:8088/proxy/application_1439458788229_0016/ Kill
>   Command = /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill
>   job_1439458788229_0016 Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of
>   mappers: 2; number of reducers: 1 2015-08-27 10:27:33,567 Stage-1 map
>   = 0%,  reduce = 0% 2015-08-27 10:27:43,908 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 0% 2015-08-27 10:27:45,015 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0% 2015-08-27 10:28:31,011 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100% Ended Job =
>   job_1439458788229_0016 with errors Error during job, obtaining
>   debugging information... Examining task ID:
>   task_1439458788229_0016_m_000001 (and more) from job
>   job_1439458788229_0016
>
> Task with the most failures(4):
>   ----- Task ID:   task_1439458788229_0016_m_000001
>
> URL:
>   http://hdmaster:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1439458788229_0016&tipid=task_1439458788229_0016_m_000001
>   ----- Diagnostic Messages for this Task: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
>           ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>           ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:140)
>           ... 22 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:328)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:338)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:109)
>           ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:141)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:302)
>           ... 24 more
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask MapReduce Jobs Launched:
>   Stage-Stage-1: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
>   Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

**When checked the logs created. It gives below message**

> 2015-08-27 10:28:48,852 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service:
>   job_1439458788229_0016, Ident:
>   (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@988145f)
>   2015-08-27 10:28:49,023 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying
>   again. Got null now. 2015-08-27 10:28:49,627 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for
>   child:
>   /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1439458788229_0016
>   2015-08-27 10:28:50,363 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is
>   deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id 2015-08-27
>   10:28:51,186 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using
>   ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ] 2015-08-27 10:28:51,534 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split:
>   Paths:/user/flume/tweets/BBMP_elections/2015/08/25/11/FlumeData.1440484157685:0+52974,/user/flume/tweets/BBMP_elections/2015/08/25/11/FlumeData.1440484188899:0+20119InputFormatClass:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
>
> 2015-08-27 10:28:51,701 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities: PLAN PATH =
>   hdfs://hdmaster:8020/tmp/hive/hduser/55daf291-b44e-414b-b3a5-e326134f9f24/hive_2015-08-27_10-26-28_312_5076847637673296334-1/-mr-10004/6e310852-ea63-4789-93f1-754147923e7f/map.xml
>   2015-08-27 10:28:51,701 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities: ***************non-local
>   mode*************** 2015-08-27 10:28:51,701 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities: local path =
>   hdfs://hdmaster:8020/tmp/hive/hduser/55daf291-b44e-414b-b3a5-e326134f9f24/hive_2015-08-27_10-26-28_312_5076847637673296334-1/-mr-10004/6e310852-ea63-4789-93f1-754147923e7f/map.xml
>   2015-08-27 10:28:51,701 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities: Open file to read in plan:
>   hdfs://hdmaster:8020/tmp/hive/hduser/55daf291-b44e-414b-b3a5-e326134f9f24/hive_2015-08-27_10-26-28_312_5076847637673296334-1/-mr-10004/6e310852-ea63-4789-93f1-754147923e7f/map.xml
>   2015-08-27 10:28:51,719 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: 
>   2015-08-27 10:28:51,720 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities: Deserializing MapWork via
>   kryo 2015-08-27 10:28:52,043 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger:  2015-08-27
>   10:28:52,080 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader: Processing
>   file
>   hdfs://hdmaster:8020/user/flume/tweets/BBMP_elections/2015/08/25/11/FlumeData.1440484157685
>   2015-08-27 10:28:52,080 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.file is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.file 2015-08-27
>   10:28:52,080 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.start is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.start 2015-08-27
>   10:28:52,080 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.length is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.length 2015-08-27
>   10:28:52,080 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask:
>   numReduceTasks: 1 2015-08-27 10:28:52,228 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
>   2015-08-27 10:28:52,228 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask:
>   mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100 2015-08-27 10:28:52,228 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080 2015-08-27
>   10:28:52,228 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart =
>   0; bufvoid = 104857600 2015-08-27 10:28:52,228 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
>
> 2015-08-27 10:28:52,243 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: Initializing operator
>   MAP[3] 2015-08-27 10:28:52,243 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: Initialization Done 3 MAP
>   2015-08-27 10:28:52,243 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator: Operator 3 MAP initialized
>   2015-08-27 10:28:52,262 WARN [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child :
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in
>   configuring object    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>     ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator
>   initialization failed     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:140)
>     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:109)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:302)
>     ... 24 more
>
> 2015-08-27 10:28:52,269 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:
>   Runnning cleanup for the task 2015-08-27 10:28:52,278 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping MapTask
>   metrics system... 2015-08-27 10:28:52,278 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics
>   system stopped. 2015-08-27 10:28:52,279 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics
>   system shutdown complete.

Please suggest. How can this issue be resolved. and why is it occuring.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a classpath problem
Root cause is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe

you can have a look here to add hive-serdes: https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example